# A card inside a dialog occupies full screen

Tags: flutter

I am using a card inside a dialog. It occupies full screen even though the child of the card has a container widget of fixed width and height. 
I am using the below code:

```
showDialog(context: context, builder: (context)
{
  return Card(
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
    elevation: 8.0,
    child: Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.80,
      height: 300,
      color: const Color(0xFF465A63)
    ),
  );
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the `Card` in a size-constraining widget like `SizedBox`, `FractionallySizedBox` or `Container`. Give it a certain size and position it on the screen using `Center` or `Align`.

By default the `showDialog()` method gives you the whole screen to compose a widget, not only the small window the `AlertDialog()` widget for example uses.

Comment: that worked!! Thank you for your answer. But the background was dim by itself.

Comment: 2022 Update: I had to use a `Dialog` widget around my `SizedBox` which wrapped my `Card` widget so it didn't take up the whole screen.

Comment: You need to wrap `SizedBox` with `Center`. And in `SizedBox` goes your `Card`. I wish I could know why wrapping in `SizedBox` with fixed W/H is not enough...